# foreach with Joomla 1.7 XMLParser

Tags: php, joomla, xml-parsing

I've tried looking for an answer in other places but the documentation on XMLParser in Joomla is really poor. Basically, I'm just trying to extract data from nodes in a XML file. If anyone could explain to me what is wrong with my syntax I would appreciate it:

```
$path    = "uploaded_xmls/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        $xml =& JFactory::getXMLParser('Simple');

        $user = & JFactory::getUser();

        if($user->id && $xml->loadFile($path)) {            
            foreach( $xml->document->track as $track ) {
                $track_id = $track->getElementByPath('id');
                $track_type = 's';              
            }
            }
```

Comment: why not use good ol' plain simplexml. it even looks like joomla is using simplexml itself (should check out the code to be sure). see also http://nl2.php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFactory::getXMLParser('simple')` returns a

> "PHP4 compatible implementation of the PHP5 interface SimpleXML"

according to the doc block.

I can't tell from your code snippet what is going wrong (and you haven't actually specified), so it could even be an issue for the format of the XML file.

You would probably be better off using `JFactory::getXML($data, $isFile)` which is just **simplexml_load_XXXX** in a wrapper. ie. `$data` can be either your XML or a path to the XML file and you set the boolean `$isFile` accordingly.

The biggest advantage, of course, is that [simplexml has plenty documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and examples/